# Python. Как вызвать функцию внутри условного оператора if?

Tags: python

Мне нужно вызвать функцию пароля в коде внутри if (пишу калькулятор). При попытке вызова появляется ошибка NameError. Можно ли вообще вызвать её?

```
def admpswd(validpass):
    validpass = 123
    return validpass
```

Код с вызовом:

```
elif (changeint == 3):
        print("Введите пароль:\n")
        mainpass = admpswd(validpass)
        Pswdinput = int(input())
        if (Pswdinput == mainpass):
            print("Отлично! Добро пожаловать!")
        else:
            print("Неверный пароль") 
            break
    else: break
```

Код ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "W:\****\CALC\main.py", line 34, in <module>
    mainpass = admpswd(validpass)
NameError: name 'validpass' is not defined
```

Comment: Смысл последнего else в том, чтобы при неверном пароле программа прекращала работу. А elif отвечает за выбор админ-меню

Comment: на какой строке ошибка?

Comment: На 34 (в ней и вызывается функция)

Comment: Почему ты говоришь o Invalid Syntax, хотя в ошибке написано NameError? Ну и самый нижний else ни к чему не относится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас в функции `admpswd` переменная `validpass` не используется в том смысле что не важно что там будет поэтому от неё надо избавиться

```
def admpswd():
    validpass = 123
    return validpass
```

и место

```
mainpass = admpswd(validpass)
```

писать

```
mainpass = admpswd()
```

Answer (score 4):

Правильнее было бы функцию поменять на:

```
def admpswd(validpass):
    return validpass == 123
```

Тогда код упростится:

```
elif (changeint == 3):
        print("Введите пароль:\n")       
        Pswdinput = int(input())
        if admpswd(Pswdinput):
            print("Отлично! Добро пожаловать!")
        else:
            print("Неверный пароль") 
            break
else: break
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, поправьте `return True if validpass == 123 else False` на `return validpass == 123`.